# What is the intuition for permuting $n$ objects where $p$ are alike

Tags: probability, permutations

If we have $n$ objects in which $p$ are objects are alike and rest are all different, then the number of permutations is $\frac{n!}{p!}$. Is there some intuition on how this is correct? why do we have to divide by $p!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have $n$ objects where $p$ are alike. If you treat them like they're all different then the number of permutations is $n!$. But since there are $p$ objects alike this won't do. This is because the $n!$ will count the same permutation multiple times because it treats the $p$ alike objects like they're different. So to avoid double counting we divide by the number of ways to arrange $p$ objects, hence $\frac{n!}{p!}$.

Comment: why divide? and why by $p!$

Comment: There are $p!$ ways to arrange $p$ objects. Any permutation of $p$ distinct objects is the same as the original permutation. The reason we divide by that is as follows, if we have some permutation of these $n$ objects, then there are $p!$ identical ones, where only the alike objects are permuted.

Comment: I understand that the number of ways to permute $p$ objects is $p!$ but why divide by $p!$. It's like saying since the number of permutations of $p$ objects is $p!$, the answer is $n! - (p!)^2$ or in fact any other claim can be made. Why is it just $\frac{n!}{p!}$

Comment: Ok so I said later in my comment, "if we have some permutation of these $n $ objects, then there are $p!$ identical ones, where only the alike objects are permuted." If we are overcounting every distinct permutation $p!$ times, then to get the one true one, we divide by $p!$.

Comment: Oh, right. I didn't see your edit. Now it makes sense... Thanks Pan!

Answer (score 1):

Take a simple case, you have one red ball, and two black ones. So $n=3$. Then how can I order then. $3! = 6$:

1. $RB_1B_2$
2. $RB_2B_1$
3. $B_1RB_2$
4. $B_1B_2R$
5. $B_2B_1R$
6. $B_2RB_1$

But this would be the case if the balls were distinguishable. If they're not, then you have

1. $RBB$
2. $RBB$
3. $BRB$
4. $BBR$
5. $BBR$
6. $BRB$

Notice that there are only $3$ unique arrangements out of the 6. We divide out $p =2!$ to get the right number of permutations. Thus there are 
$$\frac{3!}{2!\,1!} = 3$$
arrangements.